# How to count number of line break from mysql data?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to count number of line break from mysql fetched data. In mysql data there are no `<br>` , `</ br>` or `\n` available for line break, only raw data available.
Data format of mysql is :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| id |                         Data (DataType : LongText)          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|    | This is first line                                               
|  1 | This is second line
|    | This is third line
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected Output : 2 (ignore last line break)

Comment: What is the data type of `Data` column in your mysql table?

Comment: @shuwnyuantee Data type is longtext

Comment: _“In mysql data there are no `<br>`, `</ br>` or `\n` available for line break, only raw data available”_ - if there wasn’t _some kind_ of line break character, you would not get to see the content in three lines as you have shown in the first place. So is it `\r` maybe? Otherwise, you need to give us a problem explanation that makes sense first.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this :

```
SELECT 
 LENGTH(TRIM(TRAILING "\n" FROM Data)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Data,"\n",'')) 
FROM your_table;
```

This compares the difference of the length of trimmed string (remove last `\n`) with the length of the string with `\n` removed.

Will outputs : 2